# peakutils.indexes gives TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python-2.7, peakutils

I have a list of floats called self.data[_]['smooth_ISA']
I'm giving this list to peakutils.indexes() like this:

indexes = peakutils.indexes(self.data[_]['smooth_ISA'], thres=0.1, min_dist=50)

But I'm getting this error:

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

What do you think is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was able to get this to work by converting my data to a numpy array. There appears to be some change recently, in which you can't treat single scalar array as indexed array.

I was able to get this to work for me specifically by editing this within peak.py, approximately line 34.

```
    if isinstance(y, np.ndarray) and np.issubdtype(y.dtype, np.unsignedinteger):
        raise ValueError("y must be signed")
if isinstance(y, list):
        y = np.array(y)
```

I've also [opened an issue](https://bitbucket.org/lucashnegri/peakutils/issues/19/numpy-error-in-peakpy-indexes-function).

His documentation for the function does specify that it should be:

```
y : ndarray (signed)
    1D amplitude data to search for peaks.
```

[TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128830/typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-scalar-index)