# TypeError when using SLSQP solver in PyOpt library

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm getting TypeErrors when trying to run the optimization library `pyOpt`. The code I'm trying to run is the basic example given [here](http://www.pyopt.org/examples/examples.tp037.html) (I'm only testing for the SLSQP solver).

I'm getting the following error during the execution of the solver

`la = numpy.array([max(m,1)], numpy.int)`

`gg = numpy.zeros([la], numpy.float)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

I suspect the error is due to changes in numpy because of the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42444003/3079474). If that is the case, what are my options to make the library work? I can think of downgrading numpy but I don't want any unforseen changes to the other libraries in my system.

Using Python 2.7 with numpy 1.12.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

replace lz with lz[0] - the issue is with version of numpy as you noted.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyOpt/pySLSQP/pySLSQP.py

I got it to run by changing lines

```
374     gg = numpy.zeros([la[0]], numpy.float)
377     dg = numpy.zeros([la[0],n+1], numpy.float)
401     w = numpy.zeros([lw[0]], numpy.float)
404     jw = numpy.zeros([ljw[0]], numpy.intc)
```

I ended up encountering errors during execution that were not python errors but rather errors encountered during operation of the compiled code, so I just switched to using pyGMO2 and I am satisfied.